# How do you create one buffer to store multiple textures of different sizes in Vulkan

Tags: memory-management, vulkan

In my Vulkan application, I'd like to have one memory buffer that can store multiple textures of different sizes. Then, I'd like to have a `VkImageView` corresponding to each texture in the buffer. I'm unsure exactly how I can create such a buffer, here's what I came up with:

```
// Create images
VkImage images[TEXTURE_COUNT];
for (int i = 0; i < TEXTURE_COUNT, i++) {
    VkImageCreateInfo imageCreateInfo{};

    // Specific to texture i
    imageCreateInfo.extent.width  = ...
    iamgeCreateInfo.extent.height = ...
    
    // Other imageCreateInfo properties are constant across all textures
    ...

    VkCreateImage(device, &imageCreateInfo, nullptr, &images[i]);
}

// Find total size of memory buffer & image offsets
int totalSize = 0;
int offsets[TEXTURE_COUNT];
for (int i = 0; i < TEXTURE_COUNT; i++) {
    VkMemoryRequirements memoryRequirements;
    vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(device, images[i], &memoryRequirements);
    offsets[i] = totalSize;
    totalSize += memoryRequirements.size;
}

// Get memory type index of memory buffer
VkMemoryRequirements firstImageMemoryRequirements;
vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(device, images[0], &firstImageMemoryRequirements);
int memoryTypeIndex = ... // Get memory type index using firstImageMemoryRequirements.memoryTypeBits

// Allocate memory
VkMemoryAllocateInfo memoryAllocateInfo{};
memoryAllocateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
memoryAllocateInfo.allocationSize = totalSize;
memoryAllocateInfo.memoryTypeIndex = memoryTypeIndex;
VkMemory memory;
vkAllocateMemory(device, &memoryAllocateInfo, nullptr, &memory)

// Bind images to memory at corresponding offset
VkBindImageMemoryInfo bindImageMemoryInfos[TEXTURE_COUNT];
for (int i = 0; i < TEXTURE_COUNT, i++) {
    VkBindImageMemoryInfo bindImageMemoryInfo{};
    bindImageMemoryInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BIND_IMAGE_MEMORY_INFO;
    bindImageMemoryInfo.image = images[i];
    bindImageMemoryInfo.memory = memory;
    bindImageMemoryInfo.memoryOffset = offsets[i];
    bindImageMemoryInfos[i] = bindImageMemoryInfo;
}
vkBindImageMemory2(device, TEXTURE_COUNT, &bindImageMemoryInfos);

// Create image views
VkImageView imageViews[TEXTURE_COUNT];
for (int i = 0; i < TEXTURE_COUNT; i++) {
    VkImageViewCreateInfo imageViewCreateInfo{};
    imageViewCreateInfo.image = images[i];
    ...

    VkCreateImageView(device, &imageViewCreateInfo, nullptr, &imageViews[i]);
}

// Now I have a bunch of image views tied to each texture,
// where each texture is stored in one memory buffer at a certain offset.
```

Does this seem reasonable, or is this not the right way? One thing that seems a little odd to me is when I'm getting the memory type index of the memory buffer. To get this, you need an image of which I have `TEXTURE_COUNT` of, so I just pick the first image. The only image properties that very per texture is the extent width and height so I'm hoping that does not affect the memory type bits of each image. I'm assuming each image will have the same memory type bits and so I can get the memory type index using the memory type bits of the first image. Thoughts on this assumption would be great aswell.

Comment: 1. I would recommend at least checking that each image has the same memory type, just to catch dumb errors like accidentally including a different type of image in your array. 2. Surely the array of offsets should be accumulated? i.e. the `offsets[i] = memoryRequirements.size;` line should be zero for the first element, the size of that image for second element, and so on?

Comment: @stridecolossus Right, I had the offsets wrong. I've changed it to `offsets[i] = totalSize;`, and you make good point about checking the memory type to catch errors.

Comment: FYI: It's not a good idea to call a memory allocation a "buffer", when the term "buffer" already has a very specific (and *distinct*) meaning in Vulkan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every `VkImage` you use, it *must* be stored in a piece of memory appropriate to that particular `VkImage` object. This means that the offset/size must match the alignment and size for that image object, and the memory type it is being bound to *must* be one of the memory types that the image can be used with.

This must be queried *independently* for each `VkImage` object you use. Or usually; two identical `VkImage` objects (ie: created from identical `VkImageCreateInfo` structures) will have the same requirements, so if you repeat identically created `VkImage`s, then you don't need to query their requirements again. There are a few other circumstances that allow images with different creation parameters to have the same requirements, so if you want to take advantage of that, you'll need to look up the details.

If you're operating in an environment where you can control the sizes, formats, usage, and other creation parameters of images, then you can figure out what the requirements are ahead of time for these few kinds of images, and work within those restrictions. Otherwise, you're going to have to do the work of querying requirement information for your images *before* allocating their memory and then allocating memory for them once you know exactly what you need.

Alternatively, you can just allocate memory as needed in large slabs. That is, if you need a new memory allocation for a specific `VkImage` (either because the last slab is full or the image needs a new memory type), then you allocate a big block of it, then you can put later images into the same storage. This requires you to keep track of what you've put into which blocks of memory.

One problem with your code is that you don't take into account the memory *alignment* requirements for the images (`VkMemoryRequirements::alignment`). You also don't consider the possibility that not all of the images can share the same allocation; you assume they all can use the same memory type.

So you'll need to change your code accordingly.

That being said, the limitations that Vulkan imposes on implementations for `VkImage` memory requirements includes a statement that effectively says that the memory type an image requires for images will be the same for all color formats, assuming many of the other creation parameters are the same. So you shouldn't be concerned about different memory types for just changing sizes of images or having images with different formats.

The things that may kick you into using different memory types are mainly usage parameters (and color vs. depth formats). Images intended to be used as render targets can have their own memory types.

Comment: "You also don't consider the possibility that not all of the images can share the same allocation; you assume they all can use the same memory type." - I have a comment in the code snippet: "Other imageCreateInfo properties are constant across all textures" which is meant to convey that all the images share the same requirements, i.e. format, tiling, usage, etc. The only difference between the images is the width and height so I believe this is not a concern and from your answer they can share the same memory type. I could have communicated that better. Thank you for the comprehensive answer.